# NodeJS - multer - change filename depending on request attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, multer

I know that I can change the filename with multer by means of the storage object like following:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, process.env.UPLOAD_DIR);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, 'bla.png');
    }
});
const upload = multer({ storage: storage } );
```

My request, besides having the file, also contains some text attributes such as `name: myPic.png`.

Is it possible to dynamically change the filename dependent on other request attributes or within the controller like following:

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
     cb(null, `${req.body.name}.png`);
}
```

or

```
router.post('/upload', upload.single('pic'), myController.upload);

/* in controller */
upload = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {

        /* change the filename of multer here? */

    } catch (err) {
        winston.error(`Error while uploading: ${err.message}`);
        winston.error(`Stack trace: ${err.stack}`);
        sendJSONResponse(res, err, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem, did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the multer documentation it does not have access to `req.body` for other additional fields, if you test it it receives an `undefined` value, then a not so perfect but functional solution is the following, once the file is uploaded you can rename it as follows.

1. Add the native class fs for access to files option

   ```
   const fs = require('fs');
   ```
2. In `diskStorage` configuration add the name you want, for example bla.png

   ```
   var storage = multer.diskStorage({
       destination: path.join('public/images/'),
       filename: function ( req, file, cb ) {          
           cb(null, 'bla.png');          
       }
   });
   ```
3. The form with the text field for the custom name

   ```
   <form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
       <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="photo" >
       <br><!--here is the custom file name-->
       <input type="text" name="file_name">
       <br> 
       <button type="submit">Send</button>
   </form>
   ```
4. Within the post path, once you have sent the file whose name will be bla.png, you can replace that name with the one in a field of the form by accessing `req.body.field_name`

   ```
   router.post('/upload', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
       //Here change the file name bla.png for the new value in req.body.field_name + original ext of file
       fs.renameSync(req.file.path, req.file.path.replace('bla.png', 
       req.body.field_name + path.extname(req.file.originalname)));
       if(req.file) { 
           res.json(req.file);
       }
       else throw 'error';
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Multer is the middleware which both populates `req.body` AND stores the file.

Also, when it reaches the `filename()` function, there is no guarantee that the text fields will be populated in `req.body` because it depends on which order the client [sends them in](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#user-content-diskstorage) (see last note).

From what I see, you have two options:

1) Rename the uploaded file after the multer upload middleware does its thing and populates `req.body` as well as `req.file`. So in your controller upload middleware, you'd do something like:

```
if (req.file) {
    fs.renameSync(req.file.path, req.file.destination + req.body.name);
}
```

2) Change the request body text field into a query parameter. Then, inside `filename()` you can do a `req.query.name`.

Con: Not a very RESTful design, but maybe that is not so important to you.

Comment: Have you found a better way to do this?